# Google ads lag app startup time on android by a mean factor of 570ms. What can I do to reduce the impact of app loading?

Tags: android, performance, startup, app-startup, googleads-mobile-unity

The versions 1.9 and 2.0 don't have ads and hence show a considerable improvement in app startup times.

[image]

Comment: show the code how you are starting ads in your app

Comment: I am Doing it in the onCreate Method.

Comment: still need to see the code to tell whats wrong